# How can I display highest, and second highest salary using a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I display the highest, and second highest salary for an employee table in sql by using a single query?

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve that? If yes then post it for us to see.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

use rownum pseudocolumn https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297

```
with emp(emp_id, salary) 
  as (select 1, 1000 from dual union
      select 2, 3000 from dual union 
      select 3, 5000 from dual)

select * 
  from (select * 
         from emp
        order by salary desc) 
 where rownum <=2
```

output

```
    EMP_ID     SALARY
---------- ----------
         3       5000 
         2       3000
```

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your short question is:

```
SELECT salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: @Vercelli is correct. His answer is ANSI standard and will not only work in older Oracles but rivals like SQL Server.

Comment: This is also ANSI standard SQL @john, and will work on the more recent versions of [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.html) and [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx), in addition to Oracle and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, salary, rn
from (
    select empid, salary , rank() over(order by salary desc) as rn
     from emp) t
where rn<=2;
```